# View blinks after animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions, translate-animation

I have problem with any type of animations. I want to make material banner behavior, but with other animations. Actually I got the result, but the problem is that view is blinking after the animation. My code:

**First example:**

```
val anim = TranslateAnimation(1f, 1f, 1f, 0f)
anim.duration = 300
banner.startAnimation(anim)
banner.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

**Second example**

```
val mTransition = Slide(Gravity.END)
mTransition.setDuration(300)
mTransition.addTarget(banner)

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(banner, mTransition)
banner.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Can someone explain how to avoid blinking of the `view` and why it is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem of blinking of the view by animating it on other way. I used following strategy. First of all I used `Guideline` component of the `ConstraintLayout`. I constraint my banner to the top of it and place parameter `layout_constraintGuide_begin = "0dp"`. After that I used `ValueAnimator` in order to get animated value for my `Guideline` and changed the `guidebegin` params of it(see the code).

```
        val params: ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams = guideline2.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams

        animBanner = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, banner.height + toolbar.height)

        animBanner!!.addUpdateListener {
            params.guideBegin = it.getAnimatedValue() as Int
            guideline2.layoutParams = params
        }
```

This is the declaration of animation. At the end it is enough to use `animBanner.start()` for starting the animation and `animBanner.reverse()` for reverse animation (hiding banner).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the code `banner.visibility = View.INVISIBLE` and `banner.setVisibility(View.GONE)`. Try to remove it.

If you want to the `banner` is gone after the animation ended. Try to add a listener on the animation and hide the `banner` after the animation ended:

```
        val anim = TranslateAnimation(1f, 1f, 1f, 0f)
        anim.duration = 300
        anim.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {

            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                // banner.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                // or
                // banner.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            }

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
            }

        })
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks it helped to solve my problem, but now there is problem that it does not work second time after I hided it and show again. Why?

Comment: Try to loop it and in the `onAnimationStart` method call `banner.visibility = View.VISIBLE`. Note: it just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what was my problem with the help of @John Lee, but it solution does not was suitable for me, so I used `Guideline` component with `AnimatedValue`. My solution:

```
params = view.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(fromY, toY)
    anim.addUpdateListener {
        params.guideBegin = it.animatedValue as Int
        view.layoutParams = params
    }
```

So, here `fromY` value is 0, `toY` value is height of banner and view is `Guideline`, which could received by `view.height`. I should mention that first my banner is constrained to top of `Guideline`, which is placed at `constraintGuide_begin=0`. Then I animated this guideline with help of code above and using `anim.start()`, `anim.reverse()` methods.